# Venue/search endpoint not expected results

Tags: api, foursquare

could you please help me with foursquare API?

When I search by one categoryID and location it returns me 18 venues,

when I search by another categoryID and same location  it returns me 32 venues.

But when I try to search by both categories and same location it returns me only 22. In this case I expect to get venues unification, but unfortunatly it returns me some subset.

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?v=20131016&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4d4b7105d754a06376d81259&limit=50&sw=40.735975,-74.027522&ne=40.749956,-74.008163&intent=browse

Thank you

Comment: Can you give the specific categoryId's for each of the 3 requests you mentioned?

Comment: @octopi yes sure that's  4d4b7105d754a06374d81259 and 4d4b7105d754a06376d81259

Answer (score -2):

Just adding client_id & client_secret on URL parameter request,

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?v=20131016&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4d4b7105d754a06376d81259&limit=50&sw=40.735975,-74.027522&ne=40.749956,-74.008163&intent=browse&locale=en&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID_PLACE_HERE&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_PLACE_HERE

Comment: I use oAuth, API works fine and returns result. Your sugesstion doesn't solve problem with missed venues.